# Why does writing to the stream in this test work in IntelliJ's "Run", but not when I use Maven "test"?

Tags: java, outputstream, fileoutputstream, java-6, xmlstreamwriter

In my application I have a problem where the the `OutputStream` does not write anything to the file when I run "mvn clean test", but when I run it in IntelliJ by right-clicking on run testWritingToFile(), it works fine and outputs to the file.

I have the following test:

```
@Test
public void testWritingToFile() throws Exception {
    File fileXml = new File("xmltest.xml");
    OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(fileXml);
    XmlStreamWriting xmlStreamWriting = new XmlStreamWriting(outputStream);

    xmlStreamWriting.writeXmlToStream();

    outputStream.close();

}
```

Here is the class I'm calling from the test  (XmlStreamWriting.java):

```
public class XmlStreamWriting extends XmlStreamWritingBase {
    public XmlStreamWriting(OutputStream outputStream) {
        this.setOutputStream(outputStream);
    }

    public void writeXmlToStream() throws XMLStreamException {
        XMLStreamWriter xmlStreamWriter = this.getXmlStreamWriter();
        xmlStreamWriter.writeStartElement("test");
        xmlStreamWriter.writeCharacters("This is a test.");
        xmlStreamWriter.writeEndElement(); //test
    }
}
```

And here is the abstract class it extends (XmlStreamWritingBase.java):

```
public abstract class XmlStreamWritingBase {
    private XMLStreamWriter xmlStreamWriterPrivate;
    private OutputStream outputStream;

    public XMLStreamWriter getXmlStreamWriter() throws XMLStreamException {
        if(xmlStreamWriterPrivate == null) {
            XMLOutputFactory xmlOutputFactory = XMLOutputFactory.newInstance();
            xmlStreamWriterPrivate = xmlOutputFactory.createXMLStreamWriter(this.getOutputStream());
        }
        return this.xmlStreamWriterPrivate;
    }

    public OutputStream getOutputStream() {
        return outputStream;
    }

    public void setOutputStream(OutputStream outputStream) {
        this.outputStream = outputStream;
    }
}
```

I'm using the jrockit jdk 1.6.0_29 if that matters. Both IntelliJ and Maven are setup to run that JDK.

Do I have to pass the `OutputStream` to every method directly? Why doesn't the `writeXmlToStream()` method work?

EDIT: Also just to verify the stream works in both cases, I changed the test to this and when I run from maven there is no content between Test1 and Test2, but when I run with IntelliJ, the xml appears between the two strings:

```
public void testWritingToFile() throws Exception {
    File fileXml = new File("xmltest.xml");
    OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(fileXml);

    outputStream.write("Test1".getBytes());

    XmlStreamWriting xmlStreamWriting = new XmlStreamWriting(outputStream);

    xmlStreamWriting.writeXmlToStream();

    outputStream.write("Test2".getBytes());

    outputStream.close();
}
```

The output for maven is "`Test1Test2`", the output for IntelliJ "Run" is "`Test1<test>This is a test.</test>Test2`"

Comment: Define "does not work".

Comment: Clarified my question. When I said does not work, I meant that the xml file is empty.

Comment: Is there any error or warning logged during maven compile and maven surefire step?

Comment: Are you sure that maven isn't just writing the file to a location on your filesystem that you're not expecting?

Comment: Your class has a serious design mistake: if you set the output stream after having called getXmlStreamWriter(), the writer still uses the old output stream. If you have made the same mistake somehow in createXMLStreamWriter(), it could explain the difference.

Comment: @TriChu Here are the warnings when building:

[WARNING] The POM for org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3 is missing, no dependency information available //It then downloads this jar
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!

There are no other warnings.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas, if you look at my edit you can see I am looking at the correct file.

Comment: @JBNizet createXMLStreamWriter() comes from javax.xml.stream.XMLOutputFactory, I have not created this class. Also, I realize there is a possibility of creating somehow changing the output stream afterwards or not setting it properly in the first place, in my real code I only have contructors that can pass in the OutputStream (the setter has no modifier so only inherited classes can access it) and ensure that the Outputstream isn't null and isn't modified later. All the code I have in this sample project is here. There is no extra code anywhere.

Comment: I didn't realize it was a standard class. It has a flush() method (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/stream/XMLStreamWriter.html#flush%28%29). You should call it before closing the underlying stream, or even better, you should close the XML stream instead of closing the underlying stream

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was that I was not setting an encoding type. Or they differed somehow. When I set the encoding to UTF-8 the file is written to just fine:

```
xmlOutputFactory.createXMLStreamWriter(this.getOutputStream(), "UTF-8");
```

I discovered this because when I set a maven goal inside IntelliJ, the switch `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` would be appended to the end of the mvn command and then the test would correctly build the XML file.